# What is the closest thing to a modal dialog that can be used with a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, modal-dialog, user-input

In my UWP app, I need to get information from the user to store in a database. In standard Windows this is easy, of course, by creating a modal dialog form and instantiating it when needed.

But in UWP, although there *are* Dialogs, they seem limited to minimal and constrained functionality.

What I want is something at least similar to a modal dialog form, where the user would enter information I could then use to insert into the database, but the closest thing I can see available in UWP is a Page control which, I think, would effectively "replace" the main page (temporarily) if I created one for this purpose and then made it active when I needed to elicit input from the user. Is this the accepted only way to do this with UWP apps or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-19041) class to implement similar behavior as a model dialog.

Referring to `SignInContentDialog.xaml` part in the above document , you can add arbitrary UI controls to get information from the user within a panel(such as `StackPanel` or `Grid`) in `ContentDialog` and you can also set the size of the `ContentDialog` in the panel.

You can handle the data from user by adding `PrimaryButtonClick` and `CloseButtonClick` event handler(`PrimaryButtonClick` and `CloseButtonClick` are default controls of `ContentDialog`) or other `Button` controls.

Comment: A followup question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079150/why-does-the-async-await-code-to-show-my-contentdialog-fail-at-runtime

Comment: I am much closer to being where I need to be, but having a different but related problem now. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152930/how-can-i-force-the-textbox-to-display-what-is-being-entered-into-it