# How can I add a ContentDialog to my XAML without getting an err msg about it?

Tags: uwp-xaml, contentdialog

Based on the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030569/what-is-the-closest-thing-to-a-modal-dialog-that-can-be-used-with-a-uwp-app), which points to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog), I added the following between my ending "Grid" and "Page" tags:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="termsOfUseContentDialog"
       PrimaryButtonText="Accept" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="False"
       CloseButtonText="Cancel"
       Opened="TermsOfUseContentDialog_Opened">
    <ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/SmallLogo.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Terms of use"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
    <Run>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor
         congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus
         malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.</Run><LineBreak/>
    <Run>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.</Run><LineBreak/>
    <Run>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
         ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.</Run><LineBreak/>
    <Run>Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc.
         Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy.</Run>
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ConfirmAgeCheckBox" Content="I am over 13 years of age."
          Checked="ConfirmAgeCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="ConfirmAgeCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

This is a verbatim copy of what is on that page, and is just meant as a starting point, which I would tweak/customize.

It doesn't compile, though. I get these err msgs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, `duplication assignment to the Content property of the Page object`, this might be caused by adding to more than one panel in the Page.

Generally, the page xaml should looks like this:

```
<Page
 ...some references here...
 >

<Grid x:Name="FirstGrid">

</Grid></Page>
```

You could see that only one panel-Grid is set to the content of the Page.

If you add more than one panel to the page like this:

```
<Page
... some references here...>

<Grid x:Name="FirstGrid">
    
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="SecondGrid">

</Grid></Page>
```

Then you will get the error. You need to remove the second grid in the Page and keep only one panel in your Page Content.

Comment: I don't have a second grid; I'll update with the entire XAML

Comment: Actually, I just added an answer.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Glad to hear that you've found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having the ContentDialog between the ending Grid and ending Page. It needs to be within the Grid, not outside of it. IOW, this works:

```
    . . .
        <ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialog"
          Title="This is an example"
          PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
          CloseButtonText="Cancel"
          DefaultButton="Primary">
        </ContentDialog>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

...but this doesn't:

```
    . . .
    </Grid>
    <ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialog"
        Title="This is an example"
        PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
        CloseButtonText="Cancel"
        DefaultButton="Primary">
    </ContentDialog>
</Page>
```