# Why does the async/await code to show my ContentDialog fail at runtime?

Tags: uwp, async-await, uwp-xaml, contentdialog

I want to instantiate a ContentDialog in my UWP app, which is defined in my XAML as follows:

```
<Page
    . . .
    <Grid x:Name="grd">
        . . .
        <ContentDialog x:Name="cntDlgLoadMap"
            Title="This is an example"
            PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
            CloseButtonText="Cancel"
            DefaultButton="Primary">
        </ContentDialog>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Trying to get a minimal example running, I was going to try this:

```
private void btnLoadMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cntDlgLoadMap.ShowAsync();
}
```

...but got this design-time err msg:

[image]

So I changed the code to this, adding "async" to the method/event handler and "await" to the call to show the content dialog:

```
private async void btnLoadMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await cntDlgLoadMap.ShowAsync();
}
```

As such, the app compiles and runs, but when I select the "LoadMaps" button, I get this:

[image]

Then, after hitting F5 to continue, I get:

[image: ~app_g_i_cs_afterHittingF5]

What is wrong with or missing from my code or XAML?

### UPDATE

Per Roy Li's request, here is the XAML for the load button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnLoadMap" Content="Load Map" Margin="20,16,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnLoadMap_Click" />
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with the code you provide. Could you please share the 
xaml code about the `LoadMaps` button?

Comment: Sure: I updated my question with that

Comment: I have to say that I still could not reproduce the issue with the XAML code, it works correctly on my side. By the way, have you tried Michael's answer?

Comment: My bad; something else was causing the problem. It still seems odd that this err msg would appear when an exception is thrown, though; IOW: WTH?

Comment: The global unhandled exception handler is called when an exception occurs that is not otherwise handled. In other words, your app is throwing an exception somewhere, but it's not inside a `try` block (or it's in a `try` block without a `catch` clause) and this is your last chance to do something about it.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: Thanks, Peter, I put everything in a catch block now and I'll see what shakes out...

Answer (score 1):

Create your ContentDialog on the stack not on the page Xaml.  You can create a new ContentDialog class or create a UserControl class with the xaml.  See the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog?view=winrt-19041).

```
    private async void btnLoadMap_Click(object sender, 
    RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var content = new MyUserControl();
        var dialog = new ContentDialog
        {
           Content = content
        };

        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks; by "on the stack," do you mean in the C# code-behind? I looked at the sample, but got closer to grokking it (still not quite there) from this link from that one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-19041

Comment: don't put the content dialog on the xaml of your page, create it with new in your click function like I showed above.

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure about the MyUserControl part of it.

Comment: Create a new UserControl-derived class that has the Xaml for the user control. MyUserControl is an example.

Comment: I am much closer to being where I need to be, but having a different but related problem now. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152930/how-can-i-force-the-textbox-to-display-what-is-being-entered-into-it

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get it to work (pretty much/more-or-less) using the following code.

Here is the pertinent XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCre8NewMap" Content="Create New Map" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Create a new map" Margin="140,16,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnCre8NewMap_Click"/>
. . .
<ContentDialog x:Name="cntDlgCre8Map"
Title="Create a New Map"
PrimaryButtonText="Save"
CloseButtonText="Cancel"
DefaultButton="Primary">
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Map Name: "/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbxMapName"
        Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Default Zoom Level: "/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxCre8MapZoomLevels"
        Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Map Notes: "/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbxMapNotes"
        Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

...and here is the button click event in the code-behind:

```
private async void btnCre8NewMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string mapName = string.Empty;
        string mapNotes = string.Empty;
        int defaultZoomLevel = 1;
        ClearLocations();
        // Popul8 the cmbx
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            cmbxCre8MapZoomLevels.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        ContentDialogResult result = await cntDlgCre8Map.ShowAsync();

        if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {    
            mapName = txtbxMapName.Text;
            mapNotes = txtbxMapNotes.Text;
            defaultZoomLevel = cmbxCre8MapZoomLevels.SelectedIndex + 1;
            InsertMapRecord(mapName, mapNotes, preferredZoomLevel);
        }
        // else do nothing (don't save)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog exceptionMsgDlg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message, "btnCre8NewMap_Click");
        await exceptionMsgDlg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

This is what I see when I click btnCre8NewMap:

[image]